# Jenkins pipeline Continuous Integration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have 20-30 projects that I am working on with their own git repos, each repo have several branches not dependent on other projects. I am looking if there's some way to come up with Jenkins Pipeline to accommodate all the projects with CI/CD ecosystem. OR do I need to create separate pipeline for each repo.

1. Is there a way I can use one Jenkins-file into all these projects.
2. how do you share data between pipelines if module 3 is depenendent on data coming from Module1&2.
3. do I need to create 30 hooks/tokens if I have 30 projects?

I was able to create dependent build triggers between the very first three such that if A & B build then C will build using the SCM polling option and build triggers.

[image]
Thanks in advance. Appreciate any help, feedback or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared libraries in Jenkins pipelines. It is a fairly involved process requiring writing [libraries in groovy](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).

> As Pipeline is adopted for more and more projects in an organization,
> common patterns are likely to emerge. Oftentimes it is useful to share
> parts of Pipelines between various projects to reduce redundancies and
> keep code "DRY".
>
> Pipeline has support for creating "Shared Libraries" which can be
> defined in external source control repositories and loaded into
> existing Pipelines.